# Forcedroid Native Sample App Not working

Tags: mobilesdk, android

I am trying to run an app in ADT Emulator - Windows ( salesforce provided forcedroid native app FileExplorer). When i run an app against version 4.0.3 or 4.4 i am able to install the app to the device but it throws an error for internet connection . I have added the proxy settings in "Target" section in "Run Configuration" also still i'm unable to use the app.

Please let me know if i missed anything? If possible please let me know any other configuration which needs to done or steps to run the app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally see this error. But, the error goes off automatically after a while. It appears to be a server side issue.